# How to print MathML in javascript window.print() function

Tags: c#, javascript, wpf, mathml

I realize that this question may be a long shot, but I have to try regardless. 
I am doing a mathematics project in a WPF c# app, where math equations can be entered and solved. I am rendering (displaying) the equations in a web browser control (since it's the only thing that can handle MathML), and I installed MathPlayer 3.0 to enable Internet Explorer to understand mathML.

Everything has gone swimmingly until now. I want to generate a report based on the equations that the user has done in the past and want this report to be printable. Since I was using a web browser control, I thought of using the Javascript window.print() function. The only problem is that NOTHING is printed (maybe because of the mathML on the page).

So is there ANYONE out there that may have some advice to me, on how to print mathML rendered by MathPlayer in a broswer (I see on http://www.dessci.com/en/products/mathplayer/tech/accessibility.htm that it is indeed possible to print a page with MathPlayer mathML, since the said page is printable (right-click, print preview)).

Any onther comments and help of any kind is deeply appreciated!

Comment: UDPATE: The javascript function: window.print() doesn't work at all in a WPF web browser control... so does anyone know of some other way that I might print a MathML equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so this is not what I wanted, but I found a very "dirty" workaround to do what I needed.

Since Firefox is the only browser that supports MathML natively without addons, I included Firefox into the projects install. So when trying to print a document from my WPF app, I wrote all the HTML to a file and included javascript to call the document.print() function when the body is done loading. Then, I created a process to launch the HTML file I just created with Firefox, and when the browser open, the javascript will call up the print dialog.

As I said, this is far from perfect, but it was a way for me to get the mathML printed, that was being rendered in the browserControl.

NOTE: Peter Krautzberger's suggestion would have worked, but I wanted my app to run independently of an internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively use [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) to render the MathML -- printing should work fine. [Disclaimer: I'm part of the MathJax team}